# Json Object can not access with foreach?

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I am working with Laravel Rest Api and VueJS. Fetching data from an api call and after that I am modifying the returned object with some other key value. After object modification, I am trying to traverse the object using foreach, but nothing happens. The following is the code I'm working on:

```
axios.post('/api/warehouse_store_in_challan/get_product_combination_warehouse_store_in_challan_product', {
    challan_product_id: challan_product.id
  })
  .then(function(response_product_combination) {
    console.log('Here Inside');
    that.product_combination = response_product_combination.data;
    that.product_combination.name = response.data.name;
    that.product_combination.warehouse_store_in_challan_product_id = response_product_combination.data.product_combination[0].warehouse_store_in_challan_product_id;
    that.product_combination.combination = "No";
    that.product_combination.combinations = {
      'requested_quantity': response_product_combination.data.product_combination[0].requested_quantity,
      'missing_quantity': null,
      'product_id': challan_product.product_id,
      'warehouse_store_in_challan_product_id': response_product_combination.data.product_combination[0].warehouse_store_in_challan_product_id,
    };
    that.product_challan_infos_no_combination.product_combination_list.push(that.product_combination);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    that.errors = error;
  });
```

And to iterate the object I use the code below:

```
    $.each(that.product_challan_infos_no_combination.product_combination_list, function(index_product_combination_list, combination) {
      console.log("Inside New Object");
      console.dir(combination);
    })
```

And the modified Object is below:

[image: screenshot of the modified object]

Comment: What's your problem? The output of `console.dir` is getting what you are expecting? From log it seems ok

Comment: console.dir(combination); giving nothig, even not entering inside foreach. Not printing console.log("Inside New Object");

Comment: print the pushed array without each. `console.log(that.product_challan_infos_no_combination.product_combination_list);` Do you get the object?

Comment: no luck, still giving nothing. Even it's not my mission to do                                      console.dir(that.product_challan_infos_no_combination.product_combination_list;